# Error while implementing Experience Optimization in Content Service in Content Delivery

Tags: content-delivery, web8, microservices, experience-optimization

I am installing Experience optimization in Content delivery using this [link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D) . But while configuring the Session Content Service, I am getting the following error.

**Content Service Error::**

```
2016-09-07 11:43:41,683 ERROR ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [ODataAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tridion/smarttarget/utils/AmbientDataHelper
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.TriggerTypesProcessor.onRequestStart(TriggerTypesProcessor.java:27) ~[smarttarget_cartridge.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.ServerEngine.onRequestStart(ServerEngine.java:144) ~[web-ambient-engine-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    at com.sdl.web.content.ambient.service.AmbientServiceProvider.handleRequestStart(AmbientServiceProvider.java:80) ~[content-ambient-extension-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.ambient.odata.action.RequestStartAction.doOperation(RequestStartAction.java:46) ~[content-ambient-extension-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.ambient.odata.action.RequestStartAction.doOperation(RequestStartAction.java:21) ~[content-ambient-extension-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.write.ActionPostMethodHandler.handleWrite(ActionPostMethodHandler.java:53) ~[odata_processor-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataWriteProcessorImpl.write(ODataWriteProcessorImpl.java:57) ~[odata_processor-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:33) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:28) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.AmbientDataHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

**DXA 1.4 Error**, while accessing the content service ::

```
   2016-09-07 11:43:53,809 [7] ERROR - Item '/error-404' not found for Localization '27'
   Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/error-404' not found for Localization '27'
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\DXA\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultProvider.cs:line 93
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound() in C:\DXA\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 104
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you didn't install everything - perhaps only the cartridge. But the cartridge also uses the API, so you should install the entire 'content' role from the SDL Web Experience Optimization installation files.

Comment: I copied the jars from "\Content Delivery\roles\content\rest" to "SessionContentService\services\content-service" and it seems this issue resolved. But is this step mentioned any where? Also can I view the promotions & triggers in the "http://localhost:8081//client/v2/content.svc" as I can see the rest  of entities in it. As currently I am not able to view it.

Comment: It's documented under the installation of the content service, I believe. The content service doesn't expose Promotions and Triggers as entities, no -- that's what the XO Management service is for.