# Session service killed with DXA and XO

Tags: dxa, web8.5, experience-optimization, dxa-1.7

Followed the documentation for configuring Content (session) service to add XO capabilities. However, when I run DXA app, seeing the below class not found error in `cd_core` log file on my Content Delivery server.

Copied the two jar files to both `lib` and `service` (experienceoptimization) folders. But still facing the same issue.

Checked [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15499/error-while-implementing-experience-optimization-in-content-service-in-content-d) but of no help. Using DXA 1.7 and Web 8.5 with XO 8.

> 2017-05-15 12:43:05,380 ERROR ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [ODataAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-39] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tridion/smarttarget/utils/AmbientDataHelper
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.TriggerTypesProcessor.onRequestStart(TriggerTypesProcessor.java:27)
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.ServerEngine.onRequestStart(ServerEngine.java:144)
>       at com.sdl.web.content.ambient.service.AmbientServiceProvider.handleRequestStart(AmbientServiceProvider.java:81)
>       at com.sdl.web.content.ambient.odata.action.RequestStartAction.doOperation(RequestStartAction.java:46)
>       at com.sdl.web.content.ambient.odata.action.RequestStartAction.doOperation(RequestStartAction.java:21)
>       at com.sdl.odata.processor.write.ActionPostMethodHandler.handleWrite(ActionPostMethodHandler.java:54)
>       at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataWriteProcessorImpl.write(ODataWriteProcessorImpl.java:57)
>       at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:33)
>       at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
>       at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:28)
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.AmbientDataHelper
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:45)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:31)
>       ... 17 common frames omitted

Comment: Bharath, have you seen this post, it might be helpful: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15499/error-while-implementing-experience-optimization-in-content-service-in-content-d

Comment: Tried reinstalling after deleting previous installation of the session service. Seems to be working fine now. Will update this if I get to see the issue again